# plotting statistical data, putting years at the Xticklabel PGFplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to plot these data and i can't figure out how to put the years at the X axis, I want to display all the years not a 5 year step.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=8cm,
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Tonnes,
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1992,205.0)
(1993,297.0)
(1994,395.0)
(1995,1601.0)
(1996,213.0)
(1997,241.0)
(1998,203.0)
(1999,372.0)
(2004,300.26)
(2005,446.17)
(2006,530.4)
(2007,591.38)
(2008,948.04)
(2009,596.01)
(2010,768.448)
(2011,978.0)
(2012,1050.0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i read on the manual about a function {`\year`.} and i tried it but it didn't work. thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `dateplot` for this. Just use `xtck=data` along with

```
xticklabel style=
{/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=60,anchor=east,font=\scriptsize},
```

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=8cm,
xtick=data,
xticklabel style=
{/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=60,anchor=east,font=\scriptsize},
ylabel=Tonnes,
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1992,205.0)
(1993,297.0)
(1994,395.0)
(1995,1601.0)
(1996,213.0)
(1997,241.0)
(1998,203.0)
(1999,372.0)
(2004,300.26)
(2005,446.17)
(2006,530.4)
(2007,591.38)
(2008,948.04)
(2009,596.01)
(2010,768.448)
(2011,978.0)
(2012,1050.0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Hamza.w Glad it worked. Please remember that you can accept answers that solved your problem. Please refer: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)