# Plotting each value for x-axis when plotting from file with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to plot data from file using TikZ, and I successfully do. However, I want to plot every value for the x-axis along the x-axis and remove the comma that appears for each number.

My current output:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{kvinner.data}
anno,andel
1998,8.70
1999,22.73
2000,10.71
2001,26.32
2002,16.33
2003,23.53
2004,20.69
2005,22.08
2006,21.51
2007,26.67
2008,24.10
2009,22.33
2010,19.64
2011,21.05
2012,21.19
2013,20.44
2014,19.69
2015,21.58
2016,25.00
2017,27.38
2018,30.14
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=anno, y=andel, col sep=comma] {kvinner.data};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The x-axis contains years, and the y-axis a precentage. How may I plot year value without the comma, and plot every year value along the x-axis?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241701/31034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit cramped, but using the following preamble you can do it:

```
\begin{axis}[
        xtick = {1998, 1999, ..., 2018},
        x tick label style={
            font=\small,
            rotate=90,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,%
            scaled x ticks = false,
            set thousands separator={},
            fixed
        }]
```

[image]

Wouldn't a bar plot be more appropriate for this data?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right, it would be more appropriate with a bar plot. I'll see what I end up with. Anyhow, this is good knowledge. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can directly edit the `number format` of pgfplot options as in

```
\begin{axis}[x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled x ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed}]
    ...
    \end{axis}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{kvinner.data}
    anno,andel
    1998,8.70
    1999,22.73
    2000,10.71
    2001,26.32
    2002,16.33
    2003,23.53
    2004,20.69
    2005,22.08
    2006,21.51
    2007,26.67
    2008,24.10
    2009,22.33
    2010,19.64
    2011,21.05
    2012,21.19
    2013,20.44
    2014,19.69
    2015,21.58
    2016,25.00
    2017,27.38
    2018,30.14
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled x ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed}]
    \addplot table [x=anno, y=andel, col sep=comma] {kvinner.data};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]